# How do I get row from Excel and then put it into a Pandas dataframe as a column?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I plan to do this using only Pandas, however this is my first time using Pandas. I know that Pandas has a read_excel function.

My row in excel is the 4th row and has dates but I need these dates in a dataframe on Python in a column.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
fp = "G:\\Data\\Data2\\myfile.xlsm"
data = pd.read_excel(fp, skiprows = 4, sheet_name = "CRM View" )
```

This is all I have so far, but to my understanding this will read everything from the fourth row in my excel file, where as I only want the contents of the fourth row and then this row is to be fed as a column in my dataframe.

Comment: Any example with input and desired output along with your current efforts would be appreciated.

Comment: @zipa I have added what I have done so far. It's not much but it's all I know

Answer (score 2):

So, when you read excel your first row will be header and indices start from `0`.

If you take that into account your desired row is fetched like this:

```
import pandas as pd
fp = "G:\\Data\\Data2\\myfile.xlsm"
data = pd.read_excel(fp, sheet_name = "CRM View" )
dates_row = data.loc[2, :]
```

Now you can make that row into column like this:

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame({'Dates': dates_row})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this

```
data = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')
other_df['dates'] = data.iloc[3, :]
```